# Renewcommand with ensuremath and brackets

Tags: amsmath, package-writing, nesting

I'm making a `.sty` file (which is called `my-macros.sty` and is in my home `/texmf` directory) where I define some commands that I constantly use. Among these commands, there are the following

```
\newcommand{\apol}{}
\newcommand{\DEFapol}[2][X,Y]{\renewcommand{\apol}[1][#1]%
    {\ensuremath{#2[##1]}}}
\newcommand{\fq}[1][q]{\ensuremath{\mathbb{F}_{#1}}}
```

The apol command is to give a polynomial ring over a field. But once I change variables (from X to X,Y to X,Y,Z) and the field (from K to the rational numbers to a finite field) over and over throughout the text, I used `DEFapol` to define the variables (first argument of `DEFapol`) and the field (second argument). Note that the finite field with q elements is given by the other command `\fq`. Note also that I want X,Y to be the default variables for my polynomial ring.

When I test these commands in the following MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts,amsthm}
\usepackage{my-macros}

\begin{document}

\DEFapol[X]{K}

$\apol$

\DEFapol{K}

$\apol$

\DEFapol[X,Y,Z]{\fq}

$\apol$

\end{document}
```

the first two $\apol$ expressions are what I want them to be, but the last is not: the `\fq` command is taking [X,Y,Z] as its argument so the result is the following expression $\mathbb{F}_{[X,Y,Z]}$. But what I really wanted was it to be $\mathbb{F}_q[X,Y,Z]$. One solution for this would be to simply type

```
\DEFapol[X,Y,Z]{\fq[q]}
```

So my question is: is there another way to handle the brackets inside the definitions of my commands such that when I type

```
\DEF[X,Y,Z]{\fq}
```

I get the desired result, i.e., such that `\fq` ignores [X,Y,Z] as its argument?

Comment: What is the reasoning for using ensuremath here? You'll be using those math macros in math mode anyway

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I merely added `{}` in the `\DEFapol` macro in the part that went

```
...\ensuremath{#2{}[##1]}...
```

Here is the MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts,amsthm}

\newcommand{\apol}{}
\newcommand{\DEFapol}[2][X,Y]{\renewcommand{\apol}[1][#1]%
    {\ensuremath{#2{}[##1]}}}
\newcommand{\fq}[1][q]{\ensuremath{\mathbb{F}_{#1}}}

\begin{document}

\DEFapol[X]{K}

$\apol$

\DEFapol{K}

$\apol$

\DEFapol[X,Y,Z]{\fq}

$\apol$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Leaving aside `\ensuremath` that doesn't seem necessary (and seldom is), here's what happens with `\DEFapol[X,Y,Z]{\fq}`

```
\renewcommand{\apol}[1][X,Y,Z]{\fq[#1]}
```

When you now call `\apol`, you get

```
\fq[X,Y,Z]
```

and the definition of `\fq` produces <sub>*X,Y,Z*</sub> according to its definition.

What you want is something that avoids a possible misinterpretation of `[` as the delimiter of an optional argument; the primitive `\mathopen` comes very handy, as it transforms `[` into an Open atom, which it already is.

```
\renewcommand{\apol}[1][X,Y,Z]{{\fq}\mathopen[#1]}
```

Hence the code is

```
\newcommand{\apol}{}
\newcommand{\DEFapol}[2][X,Y]{%
  \renewcommand{\apol}[1][#1]{#2\mathopen[##1]}%
}
\newcommand{\fq}[1][q]{\mathbb{F}_{#1}}
```

On the other hand, I'm not sure this is really useful, because when you'll reread the typescript you would not remember what a particular `\apol` stands for.

Comment: I think it is useful in order to avoid creating a `\newcommand` for every polynomial ring I use during the text. About not remembering what a particular `\apol` stands for, well I can handle that. Anyway, thanks for elucidating the things!